# How to test with #if if the argument is string or object

Tags: json, backbone.js, handlebars.js

**Note** I'm not able to modify with custom functionality the way Handlebars works, I'm asking about out-of-the-box functionality.

I have this object

```
"media": {
             "mp4": "course/en/video/03_01_030_02.mp4",
             "ogv": "course/en/video/03_01_030_02.ogv",
             "subtitles": "course/en/video/03_01_030_02_sub.srt"
         }
```

which can also looks like this:

```
"media": {
             "mp4": "03_01_030_02.mp4",
             "ogv": "03_01_030_02.ogv",
             "subtitles": {
                           "en":"en/03_01_030_02_sub.srt",
                           "pl":"pl/03_01_030_02_sub.srt"
                          }
         }
```

in the `HBS` I have this:

```
      {{#if _media.subtitles}}
        {{#each _media.subtitles}} 
            <track kind="subtitles" src="{{this}}" srclang="{{@key}}" />
        {{/each}}
      {{/if}}
```

but this works for both but because `#each` enumerates object/array then string is not included (first json example). How can I test that `_media.subtitles` is object or string and then I can decide if #each needs to be used or not?

I have tried with this `HBS`:

```
      {{#if _media.subtitles}}
            {{#if _media.subtitles.list}}
                {{#each _media.subtitles}} 
                    <track kind="subtitles" src="{{this}}" srclang="{{@key}}" />
                {{/each}}
            {{else}}
                    <track kind="subtitles" src="{{_media.subtitles}}" srclang="en" />
            {{/if}}
      {{/if}}
```

and this `JSON`

```
    "_media": {
        "mp4": "03_01_020.mp4",
        "ogv": "03_01_020.ogv",
        "subtitles": {
                        "list":true,
                        "en":"en/03_01_020_sub.srt",
                        "pl":"pl/03_01_020_sub.srt"
        }   
    }
```

but then the 'list' ends up in the CC tracks list and that I can't get rid of.

**Update**
Ofcourse I can always use object alone but wanted a bit of flexibility and ease for content developer

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
You mentioned that you might have `list: true` as the first item in the `JSON`.
If you can guarantee that in case you have an object you have the property `list` set to `true` and this is the first property (which is not guaranteed by the JS, as far as I know), you can use this conditional statement to exclude the first element (see the line 4):

```
{{#if _media.subtitles}}
    {{#if _media.subtitles.list}}
        {{#each _media.subtitles}}
            {{#if @index}} {{! <-- THIS, because 0 evaluates to false }}
                <track kind="subtitles" src="{{this}}" srclang="{{@key}}" />
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <track kind="subtitles" src="{{_media.subtitles}}" srclang="en" />
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

---

`Backbone` has `Underscore` as a hard dependency.

You can therefore [register a `Handlebars` helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#conditionals) and check whether a property is an object or a string using the `Underscore`'s methods [`_.isObject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isObject) and [`_.isString()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isString):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isObject', function(test, options) {
    if (_.isObject(test)) {            // check if this is an object
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {                           // treat is as a string otherwise
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

Then, in the template you can use this helper as if it is an ordinary `if...else` statement:

```
{{#isObject _media.subtitles}}
    //do this if subtitles is an object
{{else}}
    // do that if subtitles is not an object
{{/isObject}}
```

You can change the helper to make sure that you have a string in the `else` statement:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isObject', function(test, options) {
    if (_.isObject(test)) {         // check if this is an object
        return options.fn(this);
    } else if (_.isString(test)) {  // check if this is a string
        return options.inverse(this);
    } else {                     // do nothing otherwise
        return "";
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 as it is a solution but not an answer as I have mentioned that I'm looking for out-of-the-box solution - all I can edit is the `HBS` file.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela Sorry, overlooked the note on the very first line and in bold! Have updated the answer. Essentially it is about simply excluding the first (zero-index) element.

Comment: True, but I think I will compromise devs comfort and always will use object.